# Can you manually award half the bounty to the closest wrong answer in lieu of a correct answer?

Tags: discussion, bounties, etiquette

I placed a bounty on a question, and so far there have been 3 good but not correct solutions and 2 worthless suggestions. I feel like the bounty should only be awarded in full for a correct answer, but I don't agree with the current vote consensus on which wrong answer is the closest to being correct. When the time comes to award the bounty, can I award 1/2 to the nearest wrong answer?

IF NOT:
I should say, that the close answers are still not useful in the sense that I still don't have a workable solution. However, people spent time thinking about this for me, and I want to reward that. (I have already voted up the answers with merit.) Should I just award the full bounty to the nearest solution and not accept the answer? Or should I let the bounty expire so that only 1/2 gets awarded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add your own answer indicating that no answers provided a workable solution and accept that as the answer to the question.  Let the bounty period expire without awarding anything.  Upvotes for helpful, but not correct or complete answers are sufficient reward for their help; they don't need additional recognition in the form of bounty.

Comment: Agreed, but I think you meant "Upvotes for helpful, but incorrect or incomplete answers are not sufficient."

Comment: @Rick - no I meant that the user needn't feel compelled to award bounty unless the answer is complete and correct.  If it's helpful, but not complete or correct, the bounty need not be awarded in addition to an upvote.